# Ruby on Rails: the best way to compare two dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I have a date variable, stored as a String in the 'YYYY-mm-dd' format. What is the best way to check, if that date has not already passed?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
Date.parse('2010-11-01') < Date.today
```

will return true if '2010-11-01' has already passed

Comment: Be careful with timezones... you'll only catch daylight savings bugs once per year!

Answer (score 72):

You can also use past?

```
Date.parse("2012-11-01").past?
```

Comment: Wow, this is a good one. I did try to find from the API, but could not find anything. Thanks. This is slick.

Comment: There is the opposite one if needed: `future?`: Returns true if the date/time is in the future: `Date.parse("2012-11-01").future?` will return false.

Comment: Be careful. when using past or future, you will not match if the date is the same (it is checking for strict equality). For example, if you use Timecop.freeze in specs, you might have to use `!future?()` instead of `past?` so it matches the frozen time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare some attributes of dates, you can do this too:

```rb
Date.parse('2010-11-01').month < Date.today.month
Date.parse('2010-11-01').year < Date.today.year
Date.parse('2010-11-01').day < Date.today.day
```